# Is this valid when dereferencing an iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, deque

```
 for (auto iter = dlQueue.cbegin(); iter != dlQueue.cend(); ++iter)     
        {
                // reference to the current element in the container
                if (*iter.id == listid)
                {
                        *iter.stall = newstall & 0xFFFFFFF;
                }
        }
```

when I dereference the object iter refers to will I be able to check the state of the object; ie id. Or will this just give me an iterator in return.

I can't go:

```
iter -> id
```

DlQueue is a dequeue.

Comment: If you're modifying `*iter`, you can't use `cbegin` and `cend`.

Comment: @TheBlueCat: `*iter.stall = newstall & 0xFFFFFFF;` looks like modification to me.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, sorry. I didn't read the last line.

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? It's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the code you quote is wrong.

`.` has higher precedence than unary `*`. To access a member of the element referred to by `iter` you should write `(*iter).id` or `iter->id`, not `*iter.id`.

Comment: I thought so. I only thought iter->id was for member functions.

Comment: It's for both member functions and data members.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it? If you got a compile error, please tell us what it was.
Also, it'd be really helpful to see the type of `dlQueue`.

Both `(*iter).id` and `iter->id` should result in a *const reference to id* (assuming `dlQueue` holds objects with an accessible member called `id`). You can't assign to a const reference, but this isn't related to your choice of `*iter.` or `iter->`.

---

If you need to *modify* the items you're iterating over, use `begin` instead of `cbegin` etc.

```
for (auto iter = dlQueue.begin(); iter != dlQueue.end(); ++iter)
```

Comment: It's a big project so it would require a bit of time to compile the thing.

Comment: You're asking us to syntax check some code you didn't even _try_ compiling? Good grief.

Comment: That's still not the point. I wouldn't even know if it was correct. It's a large project in 3d rendering so I doubt i'd know.

Comment: The point is the compiler can tell you it's wrong, for free (and typically without having to build the whole project)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the obvious errors in your code:

```
 for (auto iter = dlQueue.begin(); iter != dlQueue.end(); ++iter) {
   // if the id matches:
   if (iter->id == listid) {
     // assign to stall a bitmasked version of newstall:
     iter->stall = newstall & 0xFFFFFFF;
   }
 }
```

does that help?